# Layer appearing with black background

Tags: kineticjs

I'm doing a game and I have found adding the last layer that while it appears correct in Chrome or Firefox, something is going wrong, as the layer is appearing with black background.
If I disable any other layer it works ok, so It must be a problem with how many objects are in the screen.
Actually there are only 70-90 between hexagons and text, so it must not be the problem.
Code is a copy&paste from other blocks, so it should have gone bad before...

```
var rect=new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: rectW,
    height: rectH,
    fill: color,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1,
});
player.add(rect);


var texto=new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 40,
    y: 5,
    textFill: 'black',
    text: name,
    fontSize: 12,
    align: 'left',
    width: rectW/2,
});
player.add(texto);
```

Can anyone tell me if something is going wrong?

Comment: can you put your code in a jsfiddle and post the link? It's easier to see what you mean this way.

Comment: I think that the framework was updated but the tutorials haven't, I had a similar problem, check out the latest API http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Text.php as I think the textFill attribute has changed to something else.

Comment: or manually set the 'fill:' attribute to something, like white